# How to simulate Revenue using Bernoulli trials / Probabilities of Success in R?

Tags: r, probability, montecarlo, probability-theory, bernoulli-probability

I would like to simulate Revenues Scenarios upon: `price` and `est_p` (estimated probability) from the following df:

```
df <- data.frame(price        = c(200, 100, 600, 20, 100),
                 est_p        = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6),
                 actual_sale  = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

Revenue is - sum of `price`s where `actual_sale` is `TRUE`:

```
print(actual1 <- sum(df$price[df$actual_sale])) # Actual Revenue

[1] 820
```

I've created a function to simulate Bernoulli trials upon `est_p` and `price` values:

```
bernoulli <- function(df) {
        sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(x) {
                prc <- df$price[x]
                p   <- df$est_p[x]
                sample(c(prc, 0), size = 1000, replace = T, prob = c(p, 1 - p))
                })
}
```

And applied it to a sample `df`:

```
set.seed(100)
distr1 <- rowSums(bernoulli(df))
quantile(distr1)

  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
   0  700  820  920 1020
```

Looks OK, actual value = median! But when I apply the same function to increased (replicated x 1000 times) sample - `df1000`, actual Revenue is out of bounds of simulated values:

```
df1000 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(1000, df, simplify = FALSE))

print(actual2 <- sum(df1000$price[df1000$actual_sale])) 

[1] 820000

distr2 <- rowSums(bernoulli(df1000))
quantile(distr2)

    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
726780 744300 750050 754920 775800
```

Why does the actual revenue is out of the range of simulated values? Where did I make a mistake and what is the correct solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are you changing the seed values?

Comment: Well just in case. Even If I wouldn't it makes no difference to the problem.

Comment: It would, check this out then, `set.seed(100)` and run `distr1 <- rowSums(sim(df))`
 followed by `quantile(distr1)` and change the seed to 200 and run the above again see the output, it gives you a different output. The idea of the seed is to make a reproducible random sample.

Comment: The problem is revenue out of the bounds no matter set seed 100 or 200. This is what I meant.

Comment: We'll come to that, if you fix the seed constant.

Comment: I've removed second set.seed for convenience and updated the output and it's not, would you please check on your side.

Comment: Now change the `rbind` in your `do.call`  to `cbind` and see if it gives you what you want.

Comment: It seems you didn't catch the problem. Actual Revenue for the second case is 820000 since the sample size increase 1000 times by rbind replication

Comment: aren't we talking about `binomial distributions` (probability distribution)? Why is the actual revenue for the second case `820000`?

Comment: print(actual2 <- sum(df1000$price[df1000$sale]))
Sale column Indicates Actual Outcome (TRUE/FALSE).
If you have any thoughts on how to simulate revenue distribution upon mentioned above would you please share in the answer?

Comment: Is it a typo or actually `Bernulli` in the title or `Bernoulli`?

Comment: It is. fixed, thanks

Comment: I kind of figured out issue with your current approach. `temp <- bernoulli(df1000)`. You need to take `rowSums` and `quantile` of every 5 columns as they are one group. Do `lapply(seq(1, ncol(temp), 5), function(x) quantile(rowSums(temp[, x:(x + 4)])))` and they follow the same distribution of `quantile`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a space to clarify my comment which says change `rbind` to `cbind` in your `do.call`. Here it is and why I said that.

```r
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(price        = c(200, 100, 600, 20, 100),
                 est_p        = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.6),
                 actual_sale  = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))

print(actual1 <- sum(df$price[df$actual_sale])) # Actual Revenue

[1] 820

# here is where you need to change the rbind to cbind to stay within the range 
# otherwise you're essentially changing the distribution of the data and you 
# can't compare the results 
df1000 <- do.call("cbind", replicate(1000, df, simplify = FALSE))
print(actual2 <- sum(df1000$price[df1000$actual_sale])) 
[1] 820
```

Here is the `simulated` distribution, an `rbind` distribution and `cbind` distribution for you to have a visual. As you can see the `simulated` and `cbind` are the same. The `rbind` produced a different distribution. The `quantile()` or `fivenum()` are drawn from the distribution. That is why you're getting a different number.

[image: binomial_out]

Hope this helps trace the reason behind why or from where the `quantile()` is getting the numbers.